# What are the Haar measures on $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$?

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, haar-measure

Is there a concrete characterization for Haar measures on $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$? Just like that of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391338/what-is-the-haar-measures-on-sl2-mathbb-r-and-sl2-mathbb-r-sl2-mat)?

To begin with, maybe it is helpful to know the Iwasawa decomposition for elements in $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$, but I get stuck from here.

Comment: From Iwasawa, on the minimal parabolic the Haar measure is the Euclidean measure on the coordinates, up to a character on the Cartan subgroup. On the maximal compact, it is indeed possible, but actually not often helpful, to use parametrizations (Euler angles?) via the Lie algebra. In fact, usually meaningful integrals over the maximal compact are evaluated by other, more representation-theoretic, devices.